# Firebase firestore query not returning data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm querying my firestore database for a workspaceID. However, `snapshot.empty` evaluates to true, even though I can see the document with the correct ID in my firestore dashboard. Am I querying the database incorrectly? Result is `console.log("No matching documents")`

TIA

```
async function my_func(workspaceID) {
    console.log(workspaceID);
    db.collection('workspaces')
      .where('team_id', '==', workspaceID)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot);
        if (snapshot.empty) {
            console.log('No matching documents.');
            return;
        }  
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log("Error fetching doc for wsID, ", err))
};
```

EDIT

The value of `team_id` in this case is "T015KLJHGV9", and it is a string. The value of workspaceID, when I check it with `typeof workspaceID` is also a string

[image: Image of firestore setup]

Comment: Firestore's query equality conditionals are type-sensitive, so try this `.where('team_id', '==', parseInt(workspaceID, 10))`

Comment: Please edit the question to show the data that you're trying to query.  There's not much we can do to help if we can't see that your query actually matches your data.  We need to know the value of workspaceID that you're using, and the specific documents that should match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try:

```js
async function my_func(workspaceID) {
    console.log(workspaceID);
    db.collection('workspaces')
      .where('newWorkspace.team_id', '==', workspaceID)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot);
        if (!snapshot.exists) {
            console.log('No matching documents.');
            return;
        }  
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log("Error fetching doc for wsID, ", err))
};
```

Comment: Thank you - I tried this and same result. ```snapshot.exists``` evaluates to ```undefined```, so that's why the if statement was still triggered

Comment: snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.data());
    })

Comment: Nothing is printed in this case - maybe because it is an empty array?

Comment: you condition must be : *.where('newWorkspace.team_id', '==', workspaceID)*